# A decent way to transform a const list reference argument then pass to another function?

Tags: c++, function, constants

Sorry for not addressing problem precisely in the title, here's the thing.
Let's say I'm an adapter, and I have to redirect a function to another,
which are listing below:

My owner would call my function and pass an argument to me first like this:

```
void receive (const list<Obj>& Larr){
    // do some transforming
    // Then call "send"
}
```

And then I have to call someone else, but with the different container argument:

```
void send (const vector<Obj*>& Varr){
    // ....
}
```

Because of the constraints of 'const', so apparently, I CANNOT just do 'push_back' pointer of the elements iteration by iteration like:

```
void receive (const list<Obj>& Larr){
    for (list<Obj>::const_iterator it = Larr.begin(); it != Larr.end(); it++)
        // vec is my class member
        vec.push_back(&(*it));    // compile error: no match function
        // Because expected element is (Obj*) rather than (const Obj*)            
}
```

So the only way I think of is to COPY every element in Larr, then push_back their address in the vector, which I'm about to broadcast :

```
void receive (const list<Obj>& Larr){
    vector<Obj> tmp(Larr.size());
    int i = 0;
    for (list<Obj>::const_iterator it = Larr.begin(); it != Larr.end(); it++, i++){
        tmp[i] = *it;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < tmp.size(); i++)
        vec.push_back(&tmp[i]);

    // Call send here;
    send(vec);  // The lifecyle of tmp is ensured, no need to worry about
}
```

Now my question is, under this scenario, not allowing changing interface, is there any way that I can achieve this without copying every single element in the function?

Comment: Why not using `const vector<const Obj*>& Varr`? Either the list should not be const or you should have constant pointers as otherwise you can indirecly make changes that are not expected by the caller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct about the constraints of const, by definition it cannot be modified.  Your only options are to convert the list to a vector or overload your send method to support list types.

You may use the range based constructor to simplify your vector construction i.e.

```
std::vector<Obj> tmp{ Larr.begin(), Larr.end() };
```

Comment: Oh! I see! Thanks for your reply for simplification and make it more elegant :”)